# Saving payment for later with activemerchant

Tags: ruby, sinatra, stripe-payments, activemerchant, braintree

Active Merchant seems like a nice gem for payments. However, I need the ability to save a customer's payment information and then charge the card at a later date (ie, at time of shipping not at time of order placement).

Both [Braintree](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1080637-collect-payment-at-a-later-date-aka-extend-authorization-) and [Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later) have a way to do this by giving me a customer id to save to my db. Then I would use this id to charge the customer at some date.

I looked through [Active Merchant Stripe code](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/stripe.rb), and its `purchase()` has comments:

```
   # To create a charge on a customer, call
   #   purchase(money, nil, { :customer => id, ... })
```

Which seems like there's a way to get a customer id.

How do I get Active Merchant to create a customer object and return the customer id for Stripe and Braintree? And is this feature supported in activemerchant for all gateways that support this payment method?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The various methods that create or update a customer / credit card in the Braintree vault return `:customer_vault_id` on the response, [for example](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/braintree_blue.rb#L205):

```
Response.new(result.success?, message_from_result(result),
  {
    :braintree_customer => (
      customer_hash(result.customer, :include_credit_cards) if result.success?
    ),
    :customer_vault_id => (
      result.customer.id if result.success?
    ),
    :credit_card_token => (
      result.customer.credit_cards[0].token if result.success?
    )
  },
  :authorization => (result.customer.id if result.success?)
)
```

You can store that ID and use it in later calls to `purchase`.